# API response is different from expected

Tags: rust, reqwest

I am trying to call an API using this code:

```rust
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();

    let request_url = "https://mainnet-algorand.api.purestake.io/idx2/v2/assets/2751733/balances?currency-greater-than=0";
    let response = client
        .get(request_url)
        .header("x-api-key", "some_token")
        .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
        .header(ACCEPT, "application/json")
        .header("pragma", "public")
        .send()  
        .await?;

    println!("{:?}", response);
```

However , I get this response:

```
Response { url: Url { scheme: "https", cannot_be_a_base: false, username: "", password: None, host: Some(Domain("mainnet-algorand.api.purestake.io")), port: None, path: "/idx2/v2/assets/2751733/balances", query: Some("currency-greater-than=0"), fragment: None }, status: 200, headers: {"content-type": "application/json", "content-length": "153844", "connection": "keep-alive", "date": "Fri, 20 May 2022 18:25:38 GMT", "x-amzn-requestid": "097f7ef4-c2eb-4f14-bdbb-2dea89b64cb4", "access-control-allow-origin": "*", "x-amz-apigw-id": "Sb99aGZAYosFYLw=", "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-6287dd22-4f2782c668a46b573d923f7b", "x-cache": "Miss from cloudfront", "via": "1.1 649f2d5b78b576a4e054c850d1f18e2e.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)", "x-amz-cf-pop": "DXB50-C1", "x-amz-cf-id": "_jQfa-0GCf1nsAQHJ3EjHsDNfaU5lOeUWydITLCKTCVScNVO1cZsTA=="} }
```

This is my expected response.

```json
{"balances":[{"address":"AACCDJTFPQR5UQJZ337NFR56CC44T776EWBGVJG5NY2QFTQWBWTALTEN4A","amount":0,"deleted":false,"is-frozen":false,"opted-in-at-round":19008955},{"address":"AACVS4SV4HQMODFOQQWTYMDWVK4HXRCZJY3YBOTOKGLKPS3KL25ZYWPEVE","amount":0,"deleted":false,"is-frozen":false,"opted-in-at-round":11648878},{"address":"AAD5NOIWG5PAVGXNGUHB2QOBEP25TECM6HEH2M77JH6SVRZATT4GTDNE54","amount":0,"deleted":false,"is-frozen":false,"opted-in-at-round":11671802},{"address":"AAE6PW7E2JB7ILDCY5E4EYNGF3EPY7IA2AHS6IXV4K6AHNJDXA4AMRMRQQ","amount":9,"deleted":false,"is-frozen":false,"opted-in-at-round":16772798},{"address":"AAG5TXAOZM5BFTUY7QTSDBGD624WZ7XRLRIOBHQGIWOVILTAAGAS72JKT4","amount":0,"deleted":false,"is-frozen":false,"opted-in-at-round":17115104},{"address":"AASPDWFB2A6VMK6Q4MDWN3CHV2CPGFVAZWTCTXA76XG6A2O6DD3CQTOEZY","amount":0,"deleted":false,"is-frozen":false,"opted-in-at-round":11672815},{"address":"AAS4IWZK4TCQ6XNWPVE42WVSSPWPE3CHSQSFMOODFN3T4BQCVUCWYQFXCM","amount":61364525,"deleted":false,"is-frozen":false,"opted-in-at-round":16965159},{"address":"AAT6HFLOWBPXL4WW6BS7SSL2QXGBXBRXXE3WKMDQGJLOF6SJL3C2BKLPB4","amount":0,"deleted":false,"is-frozen":false,"opted-in-at-round":11674203},{"address":"AAWXFICZXSESKJRINCZCABPJBEG635D4JQMEOHWDHMICIPTL3IZUDAV2FI","amount":3,"deleted":false,"is-frozen":false,"opted-in-at-round":16996159},{"address":"AAYE4NCMW7OXCDZYVYW7J4W3ZLC45FAX5QMT4Q3AWPJ24MEOKJNWHEM2SY","amount":2,"deleted":false,"is-frozen":false,"opted-in-at-round":16965295},{"address":"ABAVFHUM7FMOGH4PL2XBUXJM3NNRSVNVEDK5FB74NOPSKKGOD5KJWZPSHI","amount":0,"deleted":false,"is-frozen":false,"opted-in-at-round":17141006}
```

I would appreciate pointers on what i am doing wrong

Comment: What response were you expecting?

Comment: You're comparing a textual representation of a Rust response object, with a JSON document you're expecting from the server. This is like comparing the in-memory members and methods of a hashmap with a physical phone book. They might contain the same data, but in the first case you're not inspecting the data, you're inspecting the structure of the hash map.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what gets returned from that call. [`Response`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html) is a struct with its own methods that you need to use to get the data. Either use [`text()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.text) to get the plain text of the response, or [`json()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.json) to deserialize it into a struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the reqwest [docs](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.text), you need to use the `text()` method on the `Response` struct to get the raw text. The code you have current prints out the `Response` struct, not its content.